# Social Feeds with Views Module

Tags: views, feeds, javascript, authentication-authorization

I've been searching high and low for a feeds module that will show Facebook and Twitter feeds with the Views Modules (Drupal 7.x). With Twitter using oauth, many Drupal 7 social feed modules haven't caught up to using oauth yet. The main reason I want to use views with the social parsers is because I want to use animation(like slide show) to show each social feed as it comes in.

I have found Social Parsers for Feeds that will work with views module but none that will work for Drupal 7.x

Does anyone have any suggestions that will allow social feed modules to be used in the views moudle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have some options:

You can use [Activity Stream](https://drupal.org/project/activitystream), the imported feeds become nodes so they can be re-created using views. You have a choice to enable only the modules you need. The Facebook add-on module also has a [Drupal 7 release](https://drupal.org/node/1889852) in the issue queue.

```
 Activity Stream builds a lifestream, a "River of You", by aggregating all your social activities in one place. Whether it's bookmarks on Del.icio.us, posts from Twitter or your blog, edits to wikis or enjoyed music and movies, anything you create can be gathered into one easy-to-read stream. Every item becomes a full Drupal node, allowing them to be searched, promoted, commented upon, and managed just like any other piece of content within Drupal.
```

Alternatively, you can use the [TB Social Feed](https://drupal.org/project/tb_social_feed), the feed items become nodes so they can also be used with views.

```
This module we have developed for our responsive Premium Drupal theme TB Wall. We contribute this module to the community and hope you can re-use it in your projects and development.

**What does this module do?**

This module aggregates content from social media sites. The module will retrieve public RSS feeds or request the API and creates a node for each item. Your website visitors will be able to see your sharings directly on your website and drive those visitors to your social media account. This way you might increase facebook fans, twitter followers etc.

We currently support facebook, twitter, vimeo, youtube, instagram, Flickr. Anyone feel free to contribute to this module so we can add up other social media channels.
```

There is also [Social Feed](https://drupal.org/project/socialfeed) which has a [Drupal 7 release](https://drupal.org/node/1748232) in the issue queue, but it creates a block for the feed items rather than a node for each.

So i guess the first two options are what you need

Comment: Activity Stream will not work for Twitter because of their new API.  Activity Stream Facebook does not seem to work with 7x ether.

Answer (score 0):

The [Social Content](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_content) module imports social posts as nodes, which can then be displayed with views. We are successfully using this with Drupal 7.

From the project page:

> This enables content from social media websites to be imported as
>   nodes.
>
> Content can be pulled from the following sites:
>
> Twitter Tweets can be pulled from user accounts and hashtags. OAuth
>   module is required.
>
> Instagram Instagram posts can be pulled from user accounts and
>   hashtags.
>
> Facebook Facebook posts can be pulled from Facebook pages.
>
> Tumblr Text, Photo and Video sources can be imported from Tumblr
>   blogs.
>
> Pinterest Content from Pinterest boards can be imported.
>
> Youtube Youtube videos from channels can be imported.
>
> SoundCloud SoundCloud tracks can be imported.
>
> Linkedin Company updates can be imported.
>
> VK VK group / user wall posts imports.
>
> Flickr Photos from public photo streams can be imported.
>
> Picasa Web Albums Photos from photo streams and albums can be
>   imported.
>
> These are all separated into individual modules within the project so
>   you can just enable the ones that you want to use.